# Setting current directory for Interactive Console in pydev (Eclipse) at console startup

Tags: django, eclipse, path, pydev, chdir

I want to start an interactive console in pydev from project directory, in order to import an app. I tried to use os.chdir at startup from Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interactive Console->Initial interpreter commands.
I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/ searching for an entry to set path but I didn't find anything.
Thanks

Edit: I had to import module first in order to import app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, I must say that after changing the initial interpreter commands to be:

```
import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
import os;os.chdir('c:\\')
```

Later doing (in the shell):

```
import os.path
os.path.abspath('.')
```

Does show the expected path... Aren't you getting that? What do you get when you do the abspath('.') in the shell after the startup?

Comment: this solution works but it is not what I need (I'm editing my question): I need to import some module, with PyDev PYTHON_PATH is set automatically in order to see my project folder, but when in the interactive console I try to import some modules from the project folder I get an exception and I cannot import them. I want to change sys.path[0]

Comment: Actually, if you configured the source folders properly within PyDev, the PYTHONPATH should be correct already when you do the launch... Can you post a screenshot of the PyDev package explorer and what you're importing which doesn't work?

Comment: You're right. I couldn't import an app but I had to import its module first. I thought I could import the app directly without importing its module. Sorry for your time :|