# PyDev console working directory

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, working-directory

When I open a PyDev console, the current working directory is my Eclipse folder. How can I configure the console to use the project folder as the current working directory? Can this be set workspace-wide? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319980/setting-current-directory-for-interactive-console-in-pydev-eclipse-at-console) is related, but unhelpful as the directory is hard coded. So far, I've discovered that the Eclipse run configuration variable `${project_loc:/selected project name}` cannot be used with Python's `os.chdir()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter, you can configure the PYTHONPATH variable used by Python under Eclipse, and add whatever project directories you want so that they are visible when executing Python inside of Eclipse.

I find it easier to execute my code outside of Eclipse and use better system tools for the PYTHONPATH. And for that matter, just use Emacs or VIM.

In general, though, you don't want to mess with the Eclipse settings that describe the workspace directory. It's better to just append project code locations to the Eclipse/PyDev PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I don't see how. The question was how to set the working directory (i.e. os.chdir()) to the project base dir when starting a console. Following your directions, io.curdir still equals "."

Comment: The question used the phrase "working directory" but it was a misnomer. The question is actually just about whether a given desired directory is on the execution path for an Eclipse-managed Python executable you are using. It is not about setting the CWD or equivalent OS-level concept of a working directory from within executing code.